# What is Nash Product?

Tags: game-engine, game-center, game-theory

I tried to look at the concept of "Nash product" but didn't find any relevant and useful literature about the purpose and working of Nash product. It would be good if someone point out to the literature or explain about it (means what it is, when, and how to use or calculate?)

Comment: this might be a conceptual program much better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: you may read this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bargaining_problem